# angular html5mode in tomcat apache 8.5.4 gives 404 on page refresh

Tags: angularjs, tomcat

I m creating war file using gulp-war and deploy it into tomcat apache server 8.5.4 on my system

it first runs on `localhost:8080/projectName/`

but whenever I refresh the page it gives *404 error* . How to fix this issue?

if I remove `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` from config file and than creat war file than it working fine

than everything works fine but URl comes with `/#/`

I tried with adding `.htaccess` file  but no difference

anyone has the solution ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution with help of [this article](http://tonyjunkes.com/blog/a-brief-look-at-the-rewrite-valve-in-tomcat-8)

1. add in */opt/tomcat/conf/context.xml*

   ```
    <!-- REWRITE VALVE -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
    <!-- // -->
   ```
2. add *rewite.config* file in specific project **WEB-INF** folder with below content such as on */opt/tomcat/webapps/projectName/WEB-INF/rewrite.config*

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(bmp|css|gif|htc|html?|ico|jpe?g|js|pdf|png|swf|txt|xml|svg|eot|woff|woff2|ttf|map)$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L]
   ```

hope it helps someone

Comment: Can also do the opposite in your RewriteCond to only accept urls that end with no extension or html: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^[^.]*(html?)?$` And you can add other page types like `^[^.]*(html?|jsp|aspx)?$` This way you don't have to keep going back to edit the rewrite.conf everytime you need to add a new file type.

Comment: When you deploy it locally, there's no project folder inside tomcat webapps. Did you do step 2 from IDE?

Answer (score 1):

This is example for The global approach :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application -->
<Context>
    <!-- REWRITE VALVE -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
    <!-- // -->

    <!-- Speed up context loading -->
    <JarScanner scanClassPath="false" />
    <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the -->
    <!-- web application will be reloaded.                                 -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

And Just jave added two most popular extensions to your list:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(bmp|css|gif|htc|html?|ico|jpe?g|js|pdf|png|swf|txt|xml|svg|eot|woff|woff2|ttf|map|json)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L]
```

I like reverse approach (comment by ) but prefer to keep it clean and readable.