# Problems with Angular deploy-url switch

Tags: angular, tomcat, spring-boot, angular-ui-router, angular-cli

I want to deploy my spring-boot webapp with angular-frontend to a tomact-server. I build the angular app with angular-cli and the following commando

```
ng build --deploy-url /mywebapp/
```

The app works but following problems still exist:

1. Each time I have to change manually the base href tag to `<base href="/mywebapp/">`. Why is this not done automatically in the build process?
2. All paths to static ressources of the 'assets' directory must also changed manually to '/mywebapp/assets' (i.e. `<img src="/mywebapp/assets/logo.png">`)
3. Browser refresh of router links URLs (subpaths) does not work anymore. (i.e. angular navigation to http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/feature1 works but if I want to refresh the same URL in the browser it does not work. I can only refresh the root URL http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/)

Comment: try `base href="."` this should solve your problem #1 & #2

Comment: for problem#3 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468479/angular-html5mode-in-tomcat-apache-8-5-4-gives-404-on-page-refresh

Comment: added as answer

Comment: problem #1 & #2 seems to be solved with base href=".". For problem #3 this one worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42599176/angular-cli-with-spring-boot

Comment: the problem is only solved with firefox browser. with internet explorer this one does not work, it always resolves to root instead of '/mywebapp/'. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: microsoft edge, firefox and chrome works but internet explorer 11 changes the url from 'http://servername/mywebapp' to 'http://servername/'.

Comment: I have changed back to base `href="/mywebapp/"` and now it also works for microsoft explorer 11 and everything seems to be fine :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever u build

build it with

```
ng build --base-href .
```

This will solve ur Problems #1 & #2

For Problem 3

This SO Post will work
[angular html5mode in tomcat apache 8.5.4 gives 404 on page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468479/angular-html5mode-in-tomcat-apache-8-5-4-gives-404-on-page-refresh)

1. add in /opt/tomcat/conf/context.xml

`<!-- REWRITE VALVE -->
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
 <!-- // -->`

2. add rewite.config file in specific project WEB-INF folder with below content
   for eg. on /opt/tomcat/webapps/projectName/WEB-INF/rewrite.config

   `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(bmp|css|gif|htc|html?|ico|jpe?g|js|pdf|png|swf|txt|xml|svg|eot|woff|woff2|ttf|map)$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L]`

   What this does is 
   for each of this route requests it redirects to index.html

Comment: this one should also work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42599176/angular-cli-with-spring-boot

Comment: @surfspider i wrote this answer on based of tomcat & This answer is based on spring boot configuration. 
u can upvote :p